# Change multiple string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list

```
task_list = ['A1.wakeup', 'A2.brush','B1.route','B2.breakfast']
```

the result i want is

```
task_list = ['1A1.wakeup', '1A2.brush','2B1.route','2B2.breakfast']
```

I use a for loop:

```
new_task_list = task_list[:]
for task in new_task_list:
    task.replace('A', '1A')
    task.replace('B','1B')

In [61]: new_task_list
Out[61]: ['A1.wakeup', 'A2.brush', 'B1.route', 'B2.breakfast']
```

It does not change, What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that strings in python are inmutable (they can not change), that's why `replace` will return a new string (the original one will be the same). To do what you want you could try:

```
new_task_list = task_list[:]
for idx, task in enumerate(new_task_list):
    new_task_list[idx] = new_task_list[idx].replace('A', '1A')
    new_task_list[idx] = new_task_list[idx].replace('B', '2B')
```

or even:

```
from operator import methodcaller
new_task_list = map(methodcaller('replace', 'B', '2B'),
                map(methodcaller('replace', 'A', '1A'), task_list))
```

Comment: You use a 'x' as trailing in 'idx',is it a recommended practice?

Comment: hmmm not really, the recommended practice would be to have meaningful variable names, in this case it's only the abbreviation for "index" and I think it's meaningful, but that's a bit subjective.

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` does not work in-place (pun unintended).

You can create a mapping of the replacements and use a list comprehension to build the new list looking up values from the mapping an prepending those to each string:

```
mapping = {'A': '1', 'B': '2'}
new_list = [mapping[x[0]]+x for x in task_list]
print(new_list)
# ['1A1.wakeup', '1A2.brush', '2B1.route', '2B2.breakfast']
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking cue from Moses Koledoye's answer

```
task_list = ['A1.wakeup', 'A2.brush','B1.route','B2.breakfast']
```

Getting the difference of ascii value of `A` (=65), `B` (=66) and `64`

```
[ str( ord(x[0]) - 64 )+x for x in task_list ]

# ['1A1.wakeup', '1A2.brush', '2B1.route', '2B2.breakfast']
```

Comment: This is what I thought about too +1

Answer (score 0):

`task` in your `for` loop is just a variable updated on each loop iteration, `task.replace('A', '1A')` doesn't change the list value *inplace*.

I would suggest the following solution with `re` module:

```
import re

task_list = ['A1.wakeup', 'A2.brush','B1.route','B2.breakfast']
new_task_list = [ re.sub(r'^(A|B)', lambda m: ('1' if m.group(1) == 'A' else '2') + m.group(1), t)
                  for t in task_list]

print(new_task_list)
```

The output:

```
['1A1.wakeup', '1A2.brush', '2B1.route', '2B2.breakfast']
```

---

Or even simpler:

```
task_list = ['A1.wakeup', 'A2.brush','B1.route','B2.breakfast']
search = {'A':'1', 'B':'2'}
new_task_list = [ (search[t[0]] if t[0] in search else '') + t for t in task_list]
print(new_task_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
task_list = ['A1.wakeup', 'A2.brush','B1.route','B2.breakfast']
task_list = [w.replace('A', '1A') for w in task_list]
task_list = [w.replace('B', '2B') for w in task_list]
```

Then, you will get

```
task_list = ['1A1.wakeup', '1A2.brush', '2B1.route', '2B2.breakfast']
```